# Calculate Avg time and Won %

Tags: sql-server, database, average

Below is my database table in the SQL server

```
Status      Start_Date          End_Date           Category
Won         2020-03-11 17:01    2020-11-17 11:36   A
Won         2020-03-11 17:00    2020-11-13 19:07   B
Won         2020-03-11 17:00    2020-11-12 13:40   A
Lost        2020-03-11 16:59    2020-11-12 13:06   B
Lost        2020-03-11 12:20    2020-11-12 12:58   C
Initiated   2020-02-11 19:31                       C
Initiated   2020-02-11 17:05                       B
Won         2020-02-11 12:25    2020-11-10 12:55   A
Lost        2020-02-11 12:23    2020-11-09 16:35   A
Lost        2020-02-11 12:22    2020-11-09 16:32   A
```

I want to get 2 outputs, one is overall stats and the 2nd is category-wise stats.

For overall I want won% and Avg time in Days, hours in a single query.

the output should be like this

```
Won%    AvgTime
4%      2 Days 13 Hours
```

and if the avg time is under 24 hours it should not display the day, only hours should be displayed.

and for category wise, the output should be like this in a single query

```
Category     Won%     AvgTime
A            4%       2 Days 13 hours
B            1%       7 hours
C            0%
```

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the following query but got confused and stopped as I don't know if I am going the right direction

```
select (
        select count(*)
        from jap.dbo.JAP_Master_Table j2
        where Status like '%won%'
    )
    , avg(DATEDIFF(day,Start_date,End_Date))
from jap.dbo.JAP_Master_Table j1
```

**Update**

i have tried further for overall results query and I get the output which is somewhat close to what I want with this query

```
select round(cast((select count(*) from jap.dbo.JAP_Master_Table j2 where Status like '%won%') as float)/ cast((count(*)) as float),2) as [Won%]
,avg(DATEDIFF(day,EntryDate,CAMStatusUpdatedon)) as AverageTime from jap.dbo.JAP_Master_Table j1
```

and the output is

```
Won%    AverageTime
0.02    11
```

but the query is not efficient and the output is only giving me average time in minutes, not in the format I wanted. I am trying but if someone can provide me with something more efficient that would be much appreciated.

Comment: attempt edited into the question.

Comment: Then [edit] it. Don't put information that's important to the question in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward aggregation, though the intricacies of what you are trying to display are not overly intuitive.  I would recommend that instead of trying to get your `x Days, y Hours, z Minutes` format from your SQL, that you do it in your presentation layer instead.  As you can see from the following example, doing this in SQL is less than ideal:

### Query

```
declare @t table([Status] varchar(20),[Start_Date] datetime,End_Date datetime,Category varchar(1));
insert into @t values
 ('Won'         ,'2020-03-11 17:01','2020-11-17 11:36','A')
,('Won'         ,'2020-03-11 17:00','2020-11-13 19:07','B')
,('Won'         ,'2020-03-11 17:00','2020-11-12 13:40','A')
,('Lost'        ,'2020-03-11 16:59','2020-11-12 13:06','B')
,('Lost'        ,'2020-03-11 12:20','2020-11-12 12:58','C')
,('Initiated'   ,'2020-02-11 19:31',null,'C')
,('Initiated'   ,'2020-02-11 17:05',null,'B')
,('Won'         ,'2020-02-11 12:25','2020-11-10 12:55','A')
,('Lost'        ,'2020-02-11 12:23','2020-11-09 16:35','A')
,('Lost'        ,'2020-02-11 12:22','2020-11-09 16:32','A')
;

select sum(case when [Status] = 'Won' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count([Status]) as [Won%]
      ,avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) as AvgTimeMins
      ,isnull((cast(nullif(avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) / 1440, 0) as varchar(5)) + ' Days, '), '')
       + isnull((cast(nullif((avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) % 1440) / 60, 0) as varchar(2)) + ' Hours, '), '')
       + isnull((cast(nullif(avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) % 60, 0) as varchar(2)) + ' Minutes'), '')
       as AvgTime
from @t;

select Category
      ,sum(case when [Status] = 'Won' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count([Status]) as [Won%]
      ,avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) as AvgTimeMins
      ,isnull((cast(nullif(avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) / 1440, 0) as varchar(5)) + ' Days, '), '')
       + isnull((cast(nullif((avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) % 1440) / 60, 0) as varchar(2)) + ' Hours, '), '')
       + isnull((cast(nullif(avg(datediff(minute,[Start_Date],End_Date)) % 60, 0) as varchar(2)) + ' Minutes'), '')
       as AvgTime
from @t
group by Category;
```

### Outputs

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+
|   Won%   | AvgTimeMins |            AvgTime             |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| 0.400000 |      369532 | 256 Days, 14 Hours, 52 Minutes |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+


+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| Category |   Won%   | AvgTimeMins |            AvgTime             |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| A        | 0.600000 |      378433 | 262 Days, 19 Hours, 13 Minutes |
| B        | 0.333333 |      354907 | 246 Days, 11 Hours, 7 Minutes  |
| C        | 0.000000 |      354278 | 246 Days, 38 Minutes           |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you so much @iamdave for the explanation as well as query and results demonstration. I will now apply the formatting in the presentation layer keeping the performance aspect as well in mind. i tested and it worked like a charm.